# Anaconda environment export should be into .yaml or .yml file?

Tags: virtualenv, anaconda

[image]I find in many places that conda environment is exported into .yaml file but in the documentation of [conda managing environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#export-the-environment-file) I see the file is exported as .yml file. Can we use both file format for export / is there a difference or one of them has a mistake in file extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - in fact, you could call the file `environment.txt` and it would still contain the same data. The file extension is only a convenience so the operating system knows which program to use to open the file.

Comment: Oh. I couldn't find a good explanation elsewhere. Thank you for the explanation.